# If $A_{m \times n}x= b$ has a unique solution and $n=3, m=4$ then how many solutions are possible for $Ax=c$, $c \in \mathbb{R}^4$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Given that $n=3, m=4$ and there's a unique solution for $A_{m \times n}$ then there must be a redundant row in $A$ because if there's a unique solution to $Ax=b$ then there must be 3 leading members (1) $\Rightarrow$ $A_{n \times n}x=b$ has a unique solution. Then $Ax=c$ also has a unique solution.

I'm not sure of my proof in general and of point (1) in particular.

Comment: There is either one solution or no solution. You can calculate the $x$ in $Ax=c$ using three linearly independent rows of $A$ (which indeed exist because $Ax=b$ has a unique solution), but then you still must check that the fourth equation also holds.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier but in general if there's a unique solution to a system this means that after elimination the reduced matrix is of echelon form. So if we have 4 equations then one of the equations will become all zeroes. So then again we'll have a unique solution no?

Comment: @ReinhardMeier but then we don't know what will become with the coefficient of the solution vector... is this what you meant?

Comment: If you transform $A$ into the echelon form, you have to transform the right-hand side ($c$) in parallel. The fourth element (let's call it $c_4'$) of the transformed $c$ will either be $0$, in which case $Ax=c$ has a solution, or it will be $\neq 0$, in which case $Ax=c$ does not have a solution. As the fourth row of the echelon form has only zeroes, we have $0x_1+0x_2+0x_3=c_4'$.

Comment: @ReinhardMeier so we can say that the 4th row has to be a linear combination of other rows?

Comment: If $Ax=b$ has a unique solution, we can conclude that *there* *are* three linearly independent rows in $A$ (not necessarily the first three rows). Transforming $A$ into row echelon form may require swapping of rows. The remaining row is obviously a linear combination of the other three, because those three span the $\mathbb{R}^3$, so every row vector is a linear combination of them.